# Can't set a file->description field in a paragraph programmatically

Tags: 8, entities, files, paragraphs

I am running a drupal 7 migration into Drupal 8 paragraphs. I am retrieving the source fid, mapping from the file migration, getting the dest file id, getting the source file description, and then creating a new file paragraph that just contains a public_file field.

Problem is that I can't find a way to set the description field of the file? I can create the paragraph with the file fine.

I have tried the following (where field_files is the name of the field in the paragraph)

```
$file->set('description', $file_title);
```

.

```
$file->field_files[0]['description'] = $file_title;
```

.

```
$paragraph->set('field_files', $file);
$paragraph->set('field_files_descriptions', $file_title);
```

I have tried creating a test paragraph through the front end containing a description field and inspected the values, and there isn't anything obvious where I can set the value,

```
$testparagraph = $paragraph->getFields();
$testfile = $file->getFields();
```

The description value is only here in the paragraph entity

```
$testparagraph['field_files']->list[0]->values['description']
```

I'm at a bit of a loss where I can set this description.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was incredibly simple

```
$paragraph->field_files->description = $file_title;
```